# how to evalute String based formulas in j2me midp 2.0?

Tags: java, java-me

I working in j2me(midp2.0) platform.I have received a formula String from a server like 
status=completed-defects along with table data.

the above status, completed, defects are table columns.so,in the status column i want to put the above formula.So, for doing this, i can able to get the value of the completed and defect column and modified the above formula as "=50-40".now i want to evaluate this Strings.Does anybody having the solution to please guide me to get this problem...

Operators are fixed : + , - , * , / , % , ( , )
and there is no limit for operators.

Comment: if you recieve data and formulae from server , isn;t is suitable to do calculation at server

Comment: the think is, i have table in my j2me application and user wants to enter some information on particullar cells ., and based on the information,i want to perform that formula to reflects the new value instead of each time sending a request to  server(reduce traffic).... so we follow this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Java Math Expression Evaluator](http://lts.online.fr/dev/java/math.evaluator/)** makes exactly what you need. It supports following functions: +, -, *, /, ^, %, cos, sin, tan, acos, asin, atan, sqrt, sqr, log, min, max, ceil, floor, abs, neg, rndr.

Sample:

```
MathEvaluator m = new MathEvaluator("-5-6/(-2) + sqr(15+x)");
m.addVariable("x", 15.1d);
System.out.println( m.getValue() );
```